# How to get user country and continent?

Tags: vb.net

I'm trying to get user's country and continent, in VB.NET.
I have searched a bit, but couldn't find anything. Thanks in advance!

Comment: A few more details are needed. Are you trying to resolve their location via the Internet or desktop app?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here are two solutions for finding the users country from their IP address:
[GetCountry Method](http://www.cyscape.com/products/chawk/docs/countryhawk/getcountry_method_net_.htm)
[VB.NET Basic API for GeoIP Country](http://www.maxmind.com/app/vb)

Could´nt find a way to match the country to an continent yet. Will let you know if I find a way.

Answer (score 1):

The short answer is you can't do this with .Net alone. You can work out the user's preferred language/locale and also their region but to work out the user's country and continent you would need a third party service like http://www.ipgp.net/ or http://ipinfodb.com. These rely on IP lookups but don't always provide 100% accuracy.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this helps?

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.globalization.cultureinfo.name%28v=vs.71%29.aspx

Comment: This will only provide the user's current language/locale and region (RegionInfo), not the country or continent.